Randomization validity based on a modulus function
I want to run an AB test on a platform that only supports assigning variants based on address_id. Each user can have multiple address_ids in our platform i.e each user_id can be mapped to multiple address_id. I want to ensure valid randomisation for each user_id. I believe I have two options for my test.

Exclude users with multiple address_ids and run the test only for users that have just one address_id. (Including users with multiple address_ids means that there might be users that got assigned to both A and B during the test based on their different address_ids and hence this violates the independence of the groups)

Create something called a bucket_number and assign buckets to different groups. This would work in the following way:

Calculate bucket number based on the supplier id. This can be calculated as supplier_id mod 10. Each supplier will always get one bucket number this way.
This bucket number would be assigned to a variant e.g bucket numbers 0-4 go to A and bucket number 5-9 go to B.
This way each supplier will always get assigned to the same variant.



I am strongly leaning towards Approach 2. i.e creating bucket numbers. But I want to check if this is still a valid randomisation approach? (Note that the original supplier_ids are numbers created in sequence so there's no reason to believe the modulus of the supplier_id can cause a bias in some way)
My question: Is Approach 2 valid?

Could you explain the sense in which "random numbers" and "created in sequence" are consistent explanations of the id number generation??

Ah good point. My oversight - the numbers are created in sequence. A supplier who signs up today e.g might get the id 123 and the next one would get 124 etc.

Okay: that's important.  In what sense is any randomization involved here?  As far as I can tell, none at all.

If you can assume that supplier_id is uniquely mapped to user_id, then Approach 2 is a convenient and commonly used Randomization: it is not good enough but acceptable
why this work? what's randomization involved?
randomization simply come from the sequence:it is depends on the time
supplier/user come to sign up. image a table like this



supplier/user
sign-up time
supplier_id




john
09:00:12
1


mike
09:00:13
2


alice
09:00:14
3



In this example, John signed up before Mike, but what does this mean? Actually, not much. The last digit of the timestamp contains very little information. Using the modulus operation (e.g., mod 10) is essentially like taking the last digit of the timestamp, which is almost random.
Why use mod 10 instead of mod 2?
In  case, mod 2 might be more straightforward. However, if you want to split, say, 30% of users into a treatment group, you might use mod 10 instead. For example, if mod 10 returns 0, 1, or 2, the user goes into the treatment group, while 3-9 would fall into the control group.
Why not use a truly random value?
I think you mean, why not use a PRNG(pseudo-random number generator).
A PRNG’s output depends on its seed and previous output, whereas a hash function’s output depends solely on its input. This characteristic makes using hash simpler for online A/B testing, as it is easier to reason about the results.
For example, we can convert a hash function into a pseudo-random number generator:
import mmh3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def hash_rng(seed=0):
    status = seed
    def rng():
        nonlocal status
        status += mmh3.hash(str(status))
        return (status % 2**32) / 2**32
    return rng
my_rng = hash_rng(seed=1000)
sample = [my_rng() for i in range(100000)]
plt.hist(sample)


Why isn't this approach perfect?
Approach 2 is widely used, which means other colleagues in your company might use the same logic. As a result, your experiment could become coupled with others’ experiments or even historical experiments, leading to unintended interference.
To avoid this coupling, you can add a salt to the supplier_id or user_id, hash it, and then take the modulus. Using a unique salt ensures that your experiment won’t interfere with others.
import mmh3
mmh3.hash('123' + 'your-secret-exp') % 2 # 


Would you please explain how computing a residue modulo 10 places ids randomly into two categories?  If you really intend computing the residual modulo 2 (that is, whether the hash is even or odd), then why bother with the id at all?  Why not use a truly random value?  Regardless, the question asks whether the systematic group assignment scheme based on id is valid: it's not asking how to fix it.

+1 for a good discussion.  But there are many applications, including this one, where a sequential id still cannot be considered sufficiently random.  In the present application, putting ids with last digits between 0 and 4 into one group and those between 5 and 9 in another group can create clusters of potentially correlated subjects.  Although in practice this usually does no harm, the potential for such correlation ought to be considered sufficient reason to avoid assigning subjects to groups in such a systematic way if that can be avoided.

yes, a sequential id still cannot be considered sufficiently random. Add salt and hash is better solution, as hash(id + salt) will maps the string almost evenly to another space, and the order is no longer a confounding factor.
